# How to tell if My Computer can Dual Monitor

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, cpu, motherboard

i know that being able to dual monitor or not depends on what sort of graphics card you have. With the pc i have i dont have an actual graphics card i am using the Integrated graphics that came with my Processor. Will i still be able to dual Monitor with the integrated graphics or would i HAVE to have an actual graphics card. The motherboard itself has a VGA port which is what the current Monitor is on. a HDMI port and a Dual link DVi port. These are what i have for a processor and a motherboard if it helps.

-AMD A10-7850K 3.7GHz Quad-Core Processor

-MSI A78M-E35 Micro ATX FM2+ Motherboard

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser.

Google is your friend: Simply searching for your motherboard model brought me to MSI's product page which says in the specs that it can support up to **three** displays, provided your CPU has an onboard GPU, which it obviously does:

https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/A78M-E35.html#hero-specification

> - This platform supports dual-display function (HDMI+VGA, HDMI+DVI, VGA+DVI) and triple-display function (HDMI+VGA+DVI)
>
> MSI Reminds You...The graphic output can only work with CPUs with
>   GPUs core inside.

FYI, In my experience, if the motherboard has multiple onboard video outputs it can support multiple displays. I don't know if this is **always** the case, this is just my observation.